# Kendo Autocomplete stopped working if count of found results is null

Tags: jquery, angularjs, autocomplete, kendo-ui

i  have following autocomplete.

Problem is that if returned result is null (No value matched to given text from input) Autocomplete stopped working, it means that preloader spinner is always displayed in input and no request is created if text is changed.

I think that problem is here but i don't know what to return or set if result is null:

```
 if(data.results == null) {
    growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('NO_ITEM_FOUND'), 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
  return false;
} else {
  options.success(data.results);
}
```

Here is the code of the method which is called each time if model value is changed (text in the autocomplete input).

Many thanks for any advice.

```
 $scope.$watch("teamDetail.newWorkerName", function(){
        console.log($scope.teamDetail.newWorkerName);

                $scope.customOptions = {
                    dataSource :  {
                        type: "json",
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        transport: {
                            read: function (options) {
                                console.log("List");
                                console.log(options.data);
                                console.log(options.data.filter.filters[0].value);
                                requestParams = {
                                    "entityName": "worker",
                                    "data" : {
                                        "page": 1,
                                        "pageSize": 20,
                                        "filter": {
                                            "logic": "or",
                                            "filters": [
                                                {
                                                    "value": $scope.teamDetail.newWorkerName,
                                                    "operator": "contains",
                                                    "field": "name",
                                                    "ignoreCase": true
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "value": $scope.teamDetail.newWorkerName,
                                                    "operator": "contains",
                                                    "field": "surname",
                                                    "ignoreCase": true
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "sort": [
                                            {
                                                "field": "name",
                                                "ord": "asc"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                };
                                ApiService.doHttpRequest(
                                    "POST",
                                    $rootScope.apiBaseUrl + "worker/search",
                                    requestParams
                                )
                                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                        // successful data retrieval
                                        console.log("request success, checking state");
                                        console.log(data);
                                        // sent status to global HTTP status service
                                        var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
                                        console.log("Status response is " + jsonResponse.result);
                                        // do something with data
                                        switch (jsonResponse.result) {
                                            case true:
                                                if(data.results == null) {
                                                    growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('NO_ITEM_FOUND'), 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                                                    return false;
                                                } else {
                                                    options.success(data.results);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            case false:
                                                growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('LIST_LOADING_ERROR'), 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                                                break;
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                        console.log("Error");
                                        console.log("Autocomplete loading error");
                                    });
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    dataTextField: "name",
                    // using  templates:
                    template: '#: data.name # #: data.surname #',
                    change  : function (option, data) {
                        console.log("change");
                        console.log(this.value());
                    },
                    select: function(e) {
                        console.log("select");
                        var item = e.item;
                        var text = item.text();
                        var index = item.index();
                        console.log(item);
                        console.log(text);
                        console.log(index);
                        var dataItem = this.dataItem(index);

                        $scope.$apply(function() {
                            $scope.teamDetail.newWorkerName = text;
                        });

                        $scope.$apply(function() {
                            $scope.teamDetail.workers.push(dataItem);
                        });
                    }
                };
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KendoUI is expecting an empty array and not a `null` or `undefined`. What you can do (if you cannot change the data returned by the server) is in the DataSource definition add a `schema` element and define a `parse` function that in case of receiving `data` as `null` returns `[]` (and empty array).

Something like:

```
dataSource: {
    transport : {
        read: ...
    },
    schema : {
        parse: function(data) {
            return data ? data : [];
        }
}
```

or you can modify your code to do:

```
if(data.results == null) {
    growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('NO_ITEM_FOUND'), 'error', $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
    // Return empty array instead of false
    return op.success([]);
} else {
    options.success(data.results);
}
```